# Error when using getGEO() in package GEOquery

Tags: r, bioconductor

I'M running the following code in R:

```
library(GEOquery)
mypath <- "C:/Users/Farzin/Desktop/BIOC"
GDS1 <- getGEO('GDS1',destdir=mypath)
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Using locally cached version of GDS1 found here:
C:/Users/Farzin/Desktop/BIOC/GDS1.soft.gz 
Error in read.table(con, sep = "\t", header = FALSE, nrows = nseries) : 
  invalid 'nlines' argument
```

Could anyone please tell me how I could get rid of this error?

Comment: Perhaps you could add more context (a sample file?) or try http://www.biostars.org/?

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same error using GEOquery (version 2.23.5) with R and Bioconductor from ubuntu (12.04), whatever GDS file I queried. Could it be that the GEOquery package is faulty ?

Answer (score 0):

*In my experience, getGEO is extremely finicky.* I commonly experience issues connecting to the GEO server. If this happens during download, getGEO leaves a partial file. But since the partial file is there, when you try to re-download, it will use this cached, partially downloaded file, and run into the error you see (which you want, because its not the full file).

**To solve this, delete the cached SOFT file and retry the download.**